# Replace only some groups with Regex

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Let's suppose I have the following regex:

```
-(\d+)-
```

and I want to replace, using C#, the Group 1 `(\d+)` with `AA`, to obtain:

```
-AA-
```

Now I'm replacing it using:

```
var text = "example-123-example";
var pattern = @"-(\d+)-";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "-AA-");
```

But I don't really like this, because if I change the pattern to match `_(\d+)_` instead, I will have to change the replacement string by `_AA_` too, and this is against the DRY principle.

**I'm looking for something like:**

Keep the matched text exactly how it is, but change Group 1 by `this text` and Group 2 by `another text`...

**Edit:**
That was just an example. I'm just looking for a generic way of doing what I said above.

It should work for:

`anything(\d+)more_text` and any pattern you can imagine.

All I want to do is replace only groups, and keep the rest of the match.

Answer (score 405, accepted):

A good idea could be to encapsulate everything inside groups, no matter if need to identify them or not. That way you can use them in your replacement string. For example:

```
var pattern = @"(-)(\d+)(-)";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "$1AA$3");
```

or using a MatchEvaluator:

```
var replaced = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, m => m.Groups[1].Value + "AA" + m.Groups[3].Value);
```

---

Another way, slightly messy, could be using a lookbehind/lookahead:

`(?<=-)(\d+)(?=-)`

Comment: I edited your answer to provide more info, but what you said is totally correct. **Don't know how I missed that I could put everything inside groups, no matter if will use them or not** `:)`. In my opinion, that solution is much better and cleaner than using lookahead and lookbehinds.

Comment: small typo, your replacement pattern should be $1AA$3

Comment: This works only when your regex pattern matches the entire input string. If your regex is supposed to return more matches, this approach won't work anymore.

Comment: In order for this to work, I had to add `.Value` to `m.Groups[1]` etc.

Comment: Also worth noting - if your replacement text starts with a number, the first solution ("$1AA$3") won't work as intended!

Comment: I like the messy way using lookbehinds/aheads - Althought the question asks what if I change `-(\d+)-` to `_(\d+)_` - Couldn't you just do `\D+\d+\D+`?

Comment: i used this: `Regex r = new Regex("(\\d*)(\\.\\w)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);` and this `r.Replace(@"C:\crexasd\dsD_3245.miu", 654+"$2")` didn't worked at all, always returneed the original string

Comment: @OscarMederos you can also use non capturing groups - good for groups you don't use. In `(?:foo)(bar)`, `$1` will replace `bar`. [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do)

Comment: Please always use named groups instead of numbers for better readability/maintainability (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962114/how-to-use-named-groups-when-performing-a-regex-replace)

Answer (score 42):

You can do this using [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
var pattern = @"(?<=-)\d+(?=-)";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "AA");
```

Answer (score 25):

I also had need for this and I created the following extension method for it:

```
public static class RegexExtensions
{
    public static string ReplaceGroup(
        this Regex regex, string input, string groupName, string replacement)
    {
        return regex.Replace(
            input,
            m =>
            {
                var group = m.Groups[groupName];
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                var previousCaptureEnd = 0;
                foreach (var capture in group.Captures.Cast<Capture>())
                {
                    var currentCaptureEnd =
                        capture.Index + capture.Length - m.Index;
                    var currentCaptureLength =
                        capture.Index - m.Index - previousCaptureEnd;
                    sb.Append(
                        m.Value.Substring(
                            previousCaptureEnd, currentCaptureLength));
                    sb.Append(replacement);
                    previousCaptureEnd = currentCaptureEnd;
                }
                sb.Append(m.Value.Substring(previousCaptureEnd));

                return sb.ToString();
            });
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var input = @"[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(""2.0.3.0"")][assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(""2.0.3.0"")]";
var regex = new Regex(@"AssemblyFileVersion\(""(?<version>(\d+\.?){4})""\)");


var result = regex.ReplaceGroup(input , "version", "1.2.3");
```

Result:

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.3")][assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.3")]
```

Comment: I like this implementation but it does not replace multiple matches. I posted a version which does

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want to change your pattern you can use the Group Index and Length properties of a matched group.

```
var text = "example-123-example";
var pattern = @"-(\d+)-";
var regex = new RegEx(pattern);
var match = regex.Match(text);

var firstPart = text.Substring(0,match.Groups[1].Index);    
var secondPart = text.Substring(match.Groups[1].Index + match.Groups[1].Length);
var fullReplace = firstPart + "AA" + secondPart;
```

Comment: Please note that this assumes and will only work for the first occurence of the match.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another nice clean option that does not require changing your pattern.

```
        var text = "example-123-example";
        var pattern = @"-(\d+)-";

        var replaced = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, (_match) =>
        {
            Group group = _match.Groups[1];
            string replace = "AA";
            return String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", _match.Value.Substring(0, group.Index - _match.Index), replace, _match.Value.Substring(group.Index - _match.Index + group.Length));
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace code:

```cs
var text = "example-123-example";
var pattern = @"-(\d+)-";
var replaced = Regex.ReplaceGroupValue(text, pattern, 1, "AA");
```

Extension class:

```cs
public static class RegexExtensions
{
    [Pure]
    public static string ReplaceGroupValue(this Regex source, string input, string groupName, string destinationValue)
    {
        return ReplaceGroupValue(
            source,
            input,
            m => m.Groups[groupName],
            p => destinationValue);
    }

    [Pure]
    public static string ReplaceGroupValue(this Regex source, string input, int groupIdx, string destinationValue)
    {
        return ReplaceGroupValue(
            source,
            input,
            m => m.Groups[groupIdx],
            p => destinationValue);
    }

    [Pure]
    public static string ReplaceGroupValue(this Regex source, string input, string groupName, Func<string, string> destinationValueSelector)
    {
        return ReplaceGroupValue(
            source,
            input,
            m => m.Groups[groupName],
            destinationValueSelector);
    }

    [Pure]
    public static string ReplaceGroupValue(this Regex source, string input, int groupIdx, Func<string, string> destinationValueSelector)
    {
        return ReplaceGroupValue(
            source,
            input,
            m => m.Groups[groupIdx],
            destinationValueSelector);
    }

    [Pure]
    private static string ReplaceGroupValue(
        Regex source,
        string input,
        Func<Match, Group> groupSelector,
        Func<string, string> destinationValueSelector)
    {
        var matchResult = source.Matches(input);

        if (matchResult.Count <= 0)
        {
            return input;
        }

        var text = input;

        foreach (var group in matchResult.OfType<Match>().Select(groupSelector).OrderByDescending(p => p.Index))
        {
            var begin = group.Index > 0 ? text.Substring(0, group.Index) : string.Empty;
            var end = group.Index + group.Length < text.Length
                ? text.Substring(group.Index + group.Length)
                : string.Empty;
            var destinationValue = destinationValueSelector.Invoke(group.Value);
            text = $"{begin}{destinationValue}{end}";
        }

        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version similar to Daniel's but replacing multiple matches:

```
public static string ReplaceGroup(string input, string pattern, RegexOptions options, string groupName, string replacement)
{
    Match match;
    while ((match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, options)).Success)
    {
        var group = match.Groups[groupName];

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        // Anything before the match
        if (match.Index > 0)
            sb.Append(input.Substring(0, match.Index));

        // The match itself
        var startIndex = group.Index - match.Index;
        var length = group.Length;
        var original = match.Value;
        var prior = original.Substring(0, startIndex);
        var trailing = original.Substring(startIndex + length);
        sb.Append(prior);
        sb.Append(replacement);
        sb.Append(trailing);

        // Anything after the match
        if (match.Index + match.Length < input.Length)
            sb.Append(input.Substring(match.Index + match.Length));

        input = sb.ToString();
    }

    return input;
```

Comment: Very nice, just what I needed, thanks. It can cause an infinite loop if the replacement something that will match again though; just gotta be careful.

Answer (score 0):

go through the below coding to get the separate group replacement.

```
new_bib = Regex.Replace(new_bib, @"(?s)(\\bibitem\[[^\]]+\]\{" + pat4 + @"\})[\s\n\v]*([\\\{\}a-zA-Z\.\s\,\;\\\#\\\$\\\%\\\&\*\@\\\!\\\^+\-\\\=\\\~\\\:\\\" + dblqt + @"\\\;\\\`\\\']{20,70})", delegate(Match mts)
                    {
                           var fg = mts.Groups[0].Value.ToString(); 
                           var fs = mts.Groups[1].Value.ToString();
                           var fss = mts.Groups[2].Value.ToString();
                               fss = Regex.Replace(fss, @"[\\\{\}\\\#\\\$\\\%\\\&\*\@\\\!\\\^+\-\\\=\\\~\\\:\\\" + dblqt + @"\\\;\\\`\\\']+", "");
                           return "<augroup>" + fss + "</augroup>" + fs;
                    }, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```