# How to use named groups when performing a Regex.Replace()

Tags: c#, regex, replace

How do I use named captures when performing Regex.Replace? I have gotten this far and it does what I want but not in the way I want it:

```
[TestCase("First Second", "Second First")]
public void NumberedReplaceTest(string input, string expected)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("(?<firstMatch>First) (?<secondMatch>Second)");
    Assert.IsTrue(regex.IsMatch(input));
    string replace = regex.Replace(input, "$2 $1");
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, replace);
}
```

I want to match the two words with named captures and then use the (named) captures when performing the replace.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Instead of `"$2 $1"`, you can use `"${secondMatch} ${firstMatch}"`.

There is a list of all the replacements you can do [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx).

Here is an abbreviated list:

**$number** - The captured group by number.

**${name}** - The captured group by name.

**$$** - $ literal.

**$&** - Entire match.

**$`** - The input string before the match.

**$'** - The input string after the match.

**$+** - The last group captured.

**$_** - The entire input string.

Comment: How can I replace a named group with some other value while keeping the rest of the string intact?

Answer (score 18):

Simply replace with `${groupName}`

```
[TestCase("First Second", "Second First")]
public void NumberedReplaceTest(string input, string expected)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("(?<firstMatch>First) (?<secondMatch>Second)");
    Assert.IsTrue(regex.IsMatch(input));
    string replace = regex.Replace(input, "${secondMatch} ${firstMatch}");
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, replace);
}
```