# Regex find and replace pattern matches with other pattern

Tags: c#, regex

It is common way to replace a pattern match with string, but I need to replace all sub-strings which match pattern from text to be matched as another pattern match, is it possible?

For example, is it possible to replace all matches to
`[0-9]{2}'[0-9]{2}` which represent all strings like `99'99` or `85'55`

To this `[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}`  which represent all strings like `99.99` or `85.55`

Is it possible? How to do this kind of replacements?
or I have to handle it manually through matches in for each loop?

Comment: Do you mean the capturing groups: [`([0-9]{2})'([0-9]{2})` > `$1.$2`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d)%27(%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d)&i=99%2799&r=%241.%242)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: If a Guru like you gives correct answer in comments how are noobs like me going to get chance to solve some simpler problems and rise up the ranks ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Good point :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: The current comment is the edited one asking for clarification. The first one was rather a direct demo of solution. Correct me if am wrong. If you had posted it as solution there wasn't a problem at all. But posting a correct solution in comment gives other users who **might** not have solution, copy yours. And if a genuine users posts his solution which is similar ( it's regex so most are similar ) it will be down voted considering it as copying answers.

Comment: If your question is to replace sub-strings like `99'99` to `99.99`, then it is as simple as to replace `'` with `.`. Otherwise, please edit your post with another proper example.

Comment: sorry, it is about grouping, sometimes you think about complex solutions, while simple one is waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Regex.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) instance function along with Regex capture groups like this:

```
var regex = new Regex("([0-9]{2})'([0-9]{2})");
string result = regex.Replace(input, "$1.$2");
```

More details about capture groups can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

Also, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962114/how-to-use-named-groups-when-performing-a-regex-replace). It shows how to use 'named' groups which might help in future.

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand you, you have something like 99'99 or 85'55 and want this to be replaced by 99.99 or 85.55?

What you might look for are capture groups, i.e. find for a matching, catch this matching and put this to the result.

the RegEx here would be `s/([0-9]{2})'([0-9]{2})/$1.$2/g`

Explanation:
`([0-9]{2})` the brackets declare the caption group. It means, whatever is captured in it, will be stored to a variable.
These Variables are `$1` and `$2`, because there were two capture groups.

When building the replacement string, just insert those variables and put the dot between them.

Comment: It's `dot` not `comma`.

Comment: Why does your regex have replacement part in it ?

Comment: because the question asker asked how to do the replacement.

Comment: I don't mean to say why you are doing replacement. I mean replacement part won't be appearing in regex. It will be separate from regex. See the answer below.

Comment: I didn't see the C# tag at first and this question seemed to be a 'standard' RegEx question, so I provided a RegEx which solves the problem, checked it with perl (in this case, it does appears in the regex).