# Regex.Replace just part of regex

Tags: c#, regex

I made this line of code

```
mystring= Regex.Replace(mystring, @"\d+IEME", "E");
```

But got a problem because I want to keep the number. Like `7IEME` replace to `7E`

Comment: this post should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005609/replace-only-some-groups-with-regex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Capture `\d+` with a group and then for replacing, use `$1` which means "Group 1" followed by `E`.

```
mystring= Regex.Replace(mystring, @"(\d+)IEME", "$1E");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using groups:

```
string mystring = "7IEME";
mystring= Regex.Replace(mystring, @"(\d+)IEME", "$1E");
```