# C# Regex - Replace with itself

Tags: c#, regex, replace

In want to format an article with HTML tags programmatically. What is the best way to find a pattern in the article and replace it with itself with the tags appended on each side? More specifically, how can I pass the match into `thematch` in the following example:

```
string formattedArticle
    = Regex.Replace(article, "^\d.+", "<em>" + thematch + "</em>");
```

Answer (score 8):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains:

> The `$&` substitution includes the entire match in the replacement string.

In fact, in their example they present a use case very similar to yours:

> Often, it is used to add a substring to the beginning or end of the matched string.

So in your case you can write:

```
Regex.Replace(article, "^\d.+", "<em>$&</em>");
```

Answer (score 2):

> replace it with itself with the tags appended on each side

Simply capture it inside the group enclosing inside parenthesis `(...)` and then access it using `$1` and replace with `<TAG>$1</TAG>`

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/dV4sE0/5)

sample code:

```
var pattern = @"^(\d.+)";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "<em>$1</em>");
```

Read more about [Replace only some groups with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005609/replace-only-some-groups-with-regex)