# Adding whitespace in front of special characters

Tags: python, regex, string

How to create a RE in Python to **add whitespace** in front of these special characters `,?!` if these special characters **stick to a word**?

Here is the input string:

```
myString= 'I like him, but is he good? Maybe he is good , smart, and strong.'
```

Desired output (if the special character doesn't stick to a word, it is not modified):

```
modifiedString= 'I like him , but is he good ? Maybe he is good , smart , and strong.'
```

I have tried this re:

```
modifiedString= re.sub('\w,' , ' ,' ,myString)
```

But it gives the wrong result. It removes the last character before coma, here's the result example:

```
modifiedString = 'I like hi , but is he good? Maybe he is goo , smar , and strong.'
```

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> import re
>>> myString= 'I like him, but is he good? Maybe he is good , smart, and strong.'
>>> re.sub('(?<=\w)([!?,])', r' \1', myString)
'I like him , but is he good ? Maybe he is good , smart , and strong.'
>>>
```

`(?<=\w)` is a lookback assertion that matches a word character.

`([!?,])` is a capture group that matches the character set `[!?,]` (you can add any more characters that you want to match inside the square brackets).

`\1` refers to the text captured by `([!?,])`.

Comment: Great explanation..It works, thanks! I wonder how the \1 works. Does it return all of the matched pattern , just like $ symbol in C# regex in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722423/c-sharp-regex-replace-with-itself ?

Comment: @SalacceoVanz - Somewhat like that.  The numbers `\1`, `\2`, etc. refer to the text matched by the various capture groups in the Regex pattern.  My pattern only has one capture group, `([!?,])`, so whatever is matched by this will be accessible through `\1`.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you are replacing character too. You need to preserve it using **group** in regex, and then specify **group number** in replacement string.

```
>>> myString = 'I like him, but is he good? Maybe he is good , smart, and strong.'
>>> re.sub(r'(\w)([,?!])' , r'\1 \2' ,myString)
'I like him , but is he good ? Maybe he is good , smart , and strong.'
```

Comment: Good alternative,thanks. I can't do the upvote yet since I have low reputation.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer , you can figure it out without regex , just use  `str.replace` :

```
>>> rep_list=['?',',','!']
>>> for i in rep_list : 
...  if i in myString:
...   myString=myString.replace(i,' '+i)
... 
>>> myString
'I like him , but is he good ? Maybe he is good  , smart , and strong.'
```

Comment: The only flaw is that it adds whitespace in front of a non-stick character, but thanks anyway.