# Replace only a part of matched regular expression in c#

Tags: c#, regex

Suppose I have following code :

```
string input = "hello everyone, hullo anything";
string pattern = "h.llo [A-z]+";
string output = Regex.Replace(input,pattern,"world");
```

(I have tried to make it as simple as possible)

Above code output is `"world, world"` while what I really want is a way to change all words following by `h.llo` to `world` and I want output to be `"hello world, hullo world"`

I was looking for a way to do this and I searched a lot and read this article:

[Replace only some groups with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005609/replace-only-some-groups-with-regex)

But I didn't get much from it and I'm not sure it's exactly what I want.

Is there any approach at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code to,

```
string input = "hello everyone, hullo anything";
string pattern = "(h.llo )[A-Za-z]+";
string output = Regex.Replace(input,pattern,"$1world");
```

`[A-z]` matches not only `A-Z`, `a-z` but also some other extra characters.

or

```
string pattern = "(?<=h.llo )[A-Za-z]+";
string output = Regex.Replace(input,pattern,"world");
```

`(?<=h.llo )` positive lookbehind asserion which asserts that the match must be preceded by `h`, `any char`, `llo` , space. Assertions won't match any single character but asserts whether a match is possible or not.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wJ5bG5/2)

Comment: Thank you it worked as expected. Yes I know that, I just did this for the sake of simplicity.