# Regex for retaining numbers in the replacement of group containing numbers

Tags: c#, regex

Regarding the possible dupe post: [Replace only some groups with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005609/replace-only-some-groups-with-regex)

This is not a dupe as the post replaces the group with static text, what I want is to replace the group by retaining the text in the group.

I have some texts which contain pattern like:

```
\super 1 \nosupersub
\super 2 \nosupersub
...
\super 592 \nosupersub
```

I want to replace them using regex such that they become:

```
<sup>1</sup>
<sup>2</sup>
...
<sup>592</sup>
```

So, I am using the following regex (note the group `(\d+)`):

```
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline; //as of v1.3.1.0 default is multiline
mytext = Regex.Replace(mytext, @"\s?\\super\s?(\d+)\s?\\nosupersub\s", @"<sup>\1</sup>", options);
```

However, instead of getting what I want, I got all the results replaced with `<sup>\1</sup>`:

```
<sup>\1</sup>
<sup>\1</sup>
...
<sup>\1</sup>
```

If I try the regex replacement using a text editor like https://www.sublimetext.com and also using `Python`, it is OK.

How to get such group replacement of `(\d+)` like that (retain the number) in `C#`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace only some groups with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005609/replace-only-some-groups-with-regex)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary the post replace the group with a static text `AA`. I want the number to be retained.

Comment: I think you need to use `$1` instead of `\1` in the replacement string.

Comment: @petelids thanks. That actually works.

Comment: [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx) lets one perform any transformations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many regex tools use the `\1` notation to refer to a group's value in the replacement pattern (same in syntax to a backreference).  For whatever reason, Microsoft chose to instead use `$1` for the notation in the .NET implementation of regex.  Note that backreferences still use the `\1` syntax in .NET.  It's only the syntax in the replacement pattern which is different.  See the **Substitutions** section of [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#substitutions) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this code and wrote it from memory so this might not work but the general idea is there.

Why use regex at all?

```
List<string> output = new List<string>();
foreach (string line in myText.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None))
{
    string alteredLine = line.Replace("\super", "").Replace("\nosupersub", "").Trim();

    int n;
    if (Int32.TryParse(alteredLine, out n))
    {
        output.Add("<sup>" + n + "</sup>");
    }
    else
    {
         //Add the original input in case it failed?
         output.Add(line);
    }
}
```

or for a linq version:

```
myText = myText.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
               .Select(l => "<sup>" + l.Replace("\super", "").Replace("\nosupersub", "").Trim() + "</sup>");
```

Comment: because regex is short.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Doesn't mean it should be the right tool, plus this could be shorter I just added in extra checks that the OP may not need.

Comment: I agree that regex is not always the best tool, but often times it is because it is so powerful and configurable (i.e. you can store the patterns in a config file or DB).  Whether or not it's the best tool for the job in this case isn't really up to us to say.  It doesn't strike me as a bad option for something even as simple as this, since for me it's shorter, easier to read, and therefore easier to maintain.  That being said, I realize that for people who aren't as familiar with it, there's a big learning curve, so that is a factor worth considering depending on your team.

Comment: Actually, I am creating a program that has to support regex group replacement for my friend. That is why I use regex. I agree that regex is not always the best tool. Well, thanks for the suggestion anyway. You got my upvote.

Comment: @StevenDoggart I love regular expressions and use them a lot, its just a lot of the time I see them being used where they possibly shouldn't be. So I like to answer regex questions with a none regex solution if one isn't already available so that others can see there are alternatives if need be.