# regex replace in lines starting with {\s between first space to ;}

Tags: regex, replace

i have some corrupt rtf files with lines like this:

```
{\s39\li0\fi0\ri0\sb0\sa0\ql\vertalt\fs22 FuÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€¦Ã‚Â¸zeile Zchn;}
                                          ^----------------------------^
```

i want to replace all [^a-zA-Z0-9_\{}; ] 
but only in lines beginning with "{\s" and ending with "};" from the first "space" to "};"

the first "space" and "};" should not be replaced.

Comment: What language/editor are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use `sed` in a terminal, you could do something like this.

```
sed -i 's/^\({\\s[^ ]*\s\).*\(\;}\)\(}\)\?$/\1\2/' filename
```

Turned my file containing:

```
{\s39\li0\fi0\ri0\sb0\sa0\ql\vertalt\fs22 FuÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€¦Ã‚Â¸zeile Zchn;}
```

To:

```
{\s39\li0\fi0\ri0\sb0\sa0\ql\vertalt\fs22 ;}
```

Comment: i try it with gnuwin sed and it works fine except there is one line wich end with ;}} instead of ;} should i use a second script with \;}}\ or is it possible to do something like (\;}}\ or \;}) in one script?

Comment: thanks, this work too  - sed -i "s/^\({\\s[^ ]*\s\).*\(\;}\|\;}}\)$/\1\2/" filename -

Comment: If you want to run it twice, yes.  Mine was set up to handle both cases so you only have to run it once.  Both ways should work fine though.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify language, here is [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pZqiXl/1/) example:

```
({\\s.+?\s)(.*)(})
```

Comment: I want to use it in SearchAndReplace. Regex101 says: ) Unmatched parenthesis

Comment: Good call, bad paste :)

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm unsure what language/technology you'd like to use here, but if using C# is an option, you can check out this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005609/replace-only-some-groups-with-regex?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).  The answer gets you almost the way there.

For your example:

```
var text = @"{\s39\li0\fi0\ri0\sb0\sa0\ql\vertalt\fs22 FuÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€¦Ã‚Â¸zeile Zchn;}";
var pattern = @"^({\\s\S*\s[a-zA-Z0-9_\{}; ]*)([^a-zA-Z0-9_\{}; ]*)([^}]*})";
var replaced = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "$1$3");
```

This will get you to replace one contiguous blob of bad characters, which addresses your example, but unfortunately, not your question.  There is probably a more elegant solution, but I think you'll have to iteratively run that expression until the input and output of Regex.Replace() are equal.