# Masking IBAN codes in C#

Tags: c#, string, masking

I have some IBAN code. For example it is Germany IBAN: `DE12500123456789012345`. I need to mask it and get result like this: `DE*****12345*******345`. But since the length of IBAN is different for each country I have following rule for masking: `{2 letters}{5 asterisks}{5 numbers}{n asterisks}{3 numbere}`. So in case DE IBAN - `DE*****12345*******345`, in case BE `BE*****12345*345`.

How to implement it with Regex for C#?

Comment: A regex is for _matching_, not "masking" - but if you want to use the result of a regex match to determine what characters to replace (with a `*` char) then that's fine, but you need to separate the two steps instead of conflating them.

Comment: You don't need regex at all. But you need to clarify that the numbers you will show is constant and the asterisks are variable right?

Comment: I'm tying to do it like this: string iban = "DE1250012345678901234";
 string pattern = @"(\d{2})(?=.{3})";
 string result = Regex.Replace(iban, pattern, m => new string('*', m.Length)); But result is DE****************234. And I understand that I have to extend patern but don't know how

Comment: @Eldar, after masking there should be visible first two letters, 8-12 numbers and last 3 numbers

Comment: If you have these numbers as standalone strings, not part of longer texts where you first need to detect, identify them and then mask, why do you consider using regex at all?

Comment: A regex way can probably just be a mere `Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=^[A-Z]{2}(?:\d{0,4}|\d{10,}(?=\d{4,}$)))\d", "*")`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well not using Regex will be more easier and more performant in your case :

```
var iban = "DE12500123456789012345";
var maskedIban = $"{iban[0..2]}{"".PadRight(5, '*')}{iban[7..12]}{"".PadRight(iban.Length -15, '*')}{iban[^3..]}";
//  ^ "DE*****12345*******345"
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FwOQ6d)

**Edit**
A regex solution which not as clean as the above, It uses named groups and a modified extension method that replaces named groups that is taken from this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25513964/12354911)

```
public static class X
{
    public static string ReplaceGroup(this Regex regex, string input, string groupName, char pattern)
    {
        return regex.Replace(input, m =>
        {
            var group = m.Groups[groupName];
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var previousCaptureEnd = 0;
            foreach (var capture in group.Captures.Cast<Capture>())
            {
                var currentCaptureEnd = capture.Index + capture.Length - m.Index;
                var currentCaptureLength = capture.Index - m.Index - previousCaptureEnd;
                sb.Append(m.Value.Substring(previousCaptureEnd, currentCaptureLength));
                sb.Append("".PadRight(currentCaptureLength,pattern));
                previousCaptureEnd = currentCaptureEnd;
            }

            sb.Append(m.Value.Substring(previousCaptureEnd));
            return sb.ToString();
        });
    }
}

// Usage
var input = "DE12500123456789012345";
var groupPattern = @"^([A-Z]{2})(?<Ast>\d{5})(\d{5})(?<Ast>.*)(\d{3})$";
var groupRegex = new Regex(groupPattern);
var x = groupRegex.ReplaceGroup(input,"Ast", '*');
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2UQNqd)

**Edit** Added @Wiktor Stribiżew solution to the benchmark:

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=^[A-Z]{2}(?:\d{0,4}|\d{10,}(?=\d{4,}$)))\d", "*")
```

Performance comparison of the three methods:

| Method | Iban | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RegexConcat | DE125(...)12345 [22] | 7,492.0 ns | 532.88 ns | 592.29 ns | 0.6457 | 7520 B |
| PureConcat | DE125(...)12345 [22] | 154.3 ns | 2.39 ns | 2.66 ns | 0.0223 | 240 B |
| PureRegex | DE125(...)12345 [22] | 7,639.8 ns | 67.17 ns | 68.98 ns | - | 72 B |

[BenchmarkFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G7GiO6)

Comment: Also good point but as I said I need to do it with Regex. Thanks a lot

Comment: Actually I've done like you propose. But how to check performance for different approaches? And sure when your approach has better performance I will use it

Comment: @Vito added a regex option and a performance comparison

Answer (score -1):

This regex example should work for both DE and BE cases.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

class Example
{
   static void Main()
   {
      string input = "DE12500123456789012345";
      string pattern = @"^([A-Z]{2})(?:.{5})(\d{5})(.*)(\d{3})$";

      MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
      
      foreach (Match match in matches)
      {
         Console.Write("{0}*****", match.Groups[1].Value);
         Console.Write("{0}", match.Groups[2].Value);
         Console.Write("{0}", string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("*",match.Groups[3].Value.Length)));
         Console.WriteLine("{0}", match.Groups[4].Value);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is still using string concatenation. And you could use padding instead of this : `string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("*",match.Groups[3].Value.Length))`